# How to identify Current Task Execution Count in Spring cloud dataflow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have explore the official documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-current-count-request-structure

Here no such details are available related to that API. Anyone can suggest where to refer for the given requirement ?

I have also explore this
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-classic-docs
But didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve a list using `/task/executions` the result will contain
`_embedded.taskExecutionResourceList` which is a list of task executions each will have `jobExecutionIds` which is an array of ids. You can use the size of this array.

If you retrieve a specific task using: `/tasks/executions/{id}`
Evalutate the size of `jobExecutionIds`

Update:
The documentation in [latest snapshot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-current-count) has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Corneil du Plessis,  extending what you have explained here if someone wants to know current task execution count they can filter the resultant list by "taskExecutionStatus": "RUNNING", and calculate the size as well.

Comment: I discovered that `launch-task-current-count` was renamed to  `get-task-current-count`
Updating main.